# In Stata, how can I group coefplot's means across categorical variable?

Tags: graphics, stata, coefplot

I'm working with `coefplot` command ([source](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457686.html), [docs](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457686.html)) in Stata plotting means of continuous variable over cateories.

Small reporoducible example:

```
sysuse auto, clear
drop if rep78 < 3
la de rep78 3 "Three" 4 "Four" 5 "Five"
la val rep78 rep78

mean mpg if foreign == 0, over(rep78)
eststo Domestic
mean mpg if foreign == 1, over(rep78)
eststo Foreign

su mpg, mean
coefplot Domestic Foreign , xtitle(Mpg) xline(`r(mean)')
```

Gives me result:

[image]

What I'd like to add is an extra 'group' label for Y axis. Trying options from regression examples doesn't seem to do the job:

```
coefplot Domestic Foreign , headings(0.rep78 = "Repair Record 1978")
coefplot Domestic Foreign , groups(?.rep78 = "Repair Record 1978")
```

Any other possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the job

```
   coefplot Domestic Foreign , xtitle(Mpg) xline(`r(mean)')  ///
      groups(Three Four Five = "Repair Record 1978")
```

I don't know however how it will handle situations with categorical variables with the same labels?